# Using a Primary key as the foreign key for multiple tables -PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a Table A (with a primary Key) ID (A.ID)

A.ID needs to be the foreign key for 2 other tables, B and C.

how can I do this in PHPMyAdmin DB: i seem to only have the option to set it as the foreign key to only one other table using INNODB

Answer (score 2):

If I guess right than you mixed the direction. I build a database where I could add multiple foreign key for one table. Do you use for creating the foreign key sql statments or do you add them with some kind of wizzard of phpmyadmin?

As far I remember I also had some trouble to setup that foreign keys so I used only SQL to enfoce that the keys also get those names I would like to have.

Comment: I was using the PHPMyAdmin, interface, but now according to your suggestion maybe I will export it and add the code manually ?. . .  this si what you are suggesting correct?

Comment: You don't need to export the database it should be enough to simple add the foreign keys with SQL. I use a SQL statment like this: `ALTER TABLE cars ADD CONSTRAINT car_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES model (model_id);`

Comment: Thank you for your code, it works - when I add only 1 FK Constraint but i get an error if i do the following, 

ALTER TABLE cars 
ADD CONSTRAINT car_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES model (model_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT car_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES manufacturer (model_id);

i.e manufacturer is another table 

Thank you very much for your help @rekire

Comment: If my answer helped you please remember to accept it. Remember also that every key constraint needs to have an unique name.